# how to do user management with identityserver4 and asp.netcore identity

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

I'm building a system with 3 projects and I'm struggling with how to implement user management. I have 3 projects, an asp.net core MVC, an asp.net core Web API and an identityserver4. I want to use asp.net core identity for user management because the framework provides a lot, but I don't know where to place it. The system itself is not a big system yet, but I want it to be scalable in the future. I've read that the only thing identityserver is suppose to do is the authentication and authorization and not deal with the user management part(create users, change permission, etc.)

In the system itself, I need to have an admin that has access to the users (through the frontend MVC) and can create new or delete users, etc.

so the question is, Should i implement all the user management functions that asp.net core identity provides in the identityserver4 project or should I build it in the web API and have the two projects access the same database. I don't want the 4th project only for user management, though I know that is the ideal solution. 
Currently, the mvc app only connects with the web API with the bearer token that identityserver provided.

Or, should I go in a new direction and use jwt token and asp.net core identity and only have two projects?

I'm very confused about this part, and I want to know what is the best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Identity Server project (and any projects that are related to it) should have access to the user database. All user info a client or a API resource needs, it needs to get it from the IS its self.
 Now, setting up Identity Server properly depends on your needs. If you want a simple one for a few apps to use, go with a single project that can sign in users and register them, and setup your clients and API resources in the config.cs files. This is not a great way to do it though. Generally, you should have a IS project for user sign in and registration, and one more project that manages those users, as well as clients and API resources. You can see a great example of it [here](https://github.com/skoruba/IdentityServer4.Admin), it also uses ASP.NET Identity, and has a STS project(Identity Server), Admin project(User, Client, API manager) and an API project(for all related db access). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that did clarify a lot. Would you suggest me to not go with a identityserver and instead use asp.net jet authentication if I only have these three applications?

Comment: IdentityServers use is having a centralized login logic and single sign on for all your Clients, and managing resource access for those clients. If you have only on client and one API resource, IdentityServer is a bit of a overkill. Read up on Identity Server features and see if its what you need. If you only need Auth for your app, going with JWT is fine by me. You could also use a IS4 quickstart(there is one with Asp.Net Identity) and add registration and bit of user managment to it, and leave the tokens to IS4.

Comment: But will one of the quickstart be okay in production?

Comment: It should be. You would prepare it for production like any other project. Its just unwieldy if you have multiple clients, since adding new clients would mean adding it into the code. They are also pretty bland looking. Security wise, they should be ok.

Comment: Do note, you wont be able to work with users directly from your MVC client if you use IS, and IS would complicate things by a margin. That wont be a problem with custom jwt middleware.

Comment: What do you menn by that I won't be able to work with users through the mvc?

Comment: Look at it like this: you have and API, a MVC client that consumes that API, and a MVC project for IdentityServer. Only IdentityServer MVC project has access to the user database, and the client and API can only ask about the user from the IS, they cant access the user db. If you combine IS into your MVC client, it loses its purpose.

Comment: Okay thank you so much for helping me. I'm learning towards jwt token instead of identityserver now. But just a last question. If I decides to keep the identityserver, and want a admin user that can control other users, would it be fine to implement it on the identityserver and make the mvc app call the identityserver for managing other users

Comment: You cant manage users from a client app, only from the IS app, directily or indirectly. Admin would have to login into IS and manage users there. IS quickstarts dont have roles implemented, so you would have to implement them your self, and in that case you should go with JWT if you dont need SSO and central login.